# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un campo input solo acepte números y comas?

Tags: php, java, html

Estoy trabajando con un campo `input`, y necesito que solo acepte números y comas por ejemplo:

```
145,234,126,876,909,173
```

Ya que cada número representa un `ID`, y esos datos los guardo en un *array* en PHP con `explode`

```php
$array = explode(",", $campoinput);
```

Para posteriormente ocuparlos en otra función.

¿Cómo puedo lograr que el campo solo acepte números y comas como se muestra en el ejemplo de arriba?

Este es mi campo input:

```html
<input name="ids" id="retiros" class="input_personalizado" size="40" align="center" placeholder="Ejemplo: 194,94,29">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fijate el post: [Validar input solo decimal y coma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244124/validar-input-solo-decimal-y-coma).

Es lo que buscas, solo debes cambiar esta linea:

```
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
```

por:

```
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

En el `input` puedes utilizar el atributo `pattern` para especificar una expresión regular (un patrón) que el campo debe cumplir para que se considere válido. En navegadores que soporten validación HTML5 (básicamente todos), el formulario no se podrá enviar si alguno de los campos no es válido.

Una expresión regular simple que podría servirte es `[0-9,]+` que indica que el campo debe tener solo dígitos y comas. Pero esta expresión regular es muy básica y aceptará algunas cadenas que no te interesen, como por ejemplo `,,,,`.

Puedes optar por otra expresión regular algo más compleja: `^[0-9]+([,]?[0-9]+)*$`. Este patrón indica que el campo debe:

- Tener al menos un dígito
- Que el primer carácter sea un dígito
- Puede estar seguido opcionalmente por 0 o más de esto:

  - una coma opcional
  - al menos un dígito

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando:

```html
<form>
  <input name="ids" 
         id="retiros" 
         class="input_personalizado" 
         size="40" 
         align="center" 
         placeholder="Ejemplo: 194,94,29" 
         pattern="^[0-9]+([,]?[0-9]+)*$" />
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Alguien con más experiencia en expresiones regulares seguramente puede dar un patrón mejor o más eficaz. En mi opinión (y es una opinión), dejaría que el navegador hiciera el trabajo por ti.

Comment: El "diseñador" en mí recomendaría no usar un `input` para esto. Podrías crear un pequeño componente que tenga un `input` y añada chips (que tendría un checkbox escondido con un nombre común). PHP pone todos los valores de campos con el mismo name en un array directamente.

Comment: Algo como esto: https://codepen.io/alvaromontoro/pen/RwKyJBV